# Problem flipping/duplicating keyframes

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, dopesheet

I seem to be having issues with flipping and duplicating some keyframes. I've tried using Ctrl + C, Shift + Ctrl + V and duplicating keyframes in the Dope Sheet, but I can't get copied frames to work properly. I've already keyframed the motion of the left and right legs/feet, but whenever I try and duplicate what I've done for later in the timeline, such as the left leg, it gets stretched out of proportion. :-\ I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong or what I should be adjusting instead.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least make sure that your armature is symmetrized. As you can see it is not. So in *Edit* mode select the left (or right) part and *Symmetrize*. Also, you'll have to correct the *Pole Angle* of some bones like the forearm, fingers...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll play around with it after both sides are now symmetrical. I can't say changing the pole angle has helped though. Putting the right one to 90 degrees just twists the arm around the wrong way.

Comment: Yes it depends on which side you've symmetrized, find the right pole angle  ;)

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it. I take it it's just a case of repositioning the arm/hand for it to untwirl and be in the correct direction...?

Comment: once you've symmetrized you often (always?) need to twist some of your IK bones so that they are correctly oriented, but it was not your problem, I think it has too see with a bad symmetry, I'm not sure though, you need to test.

Comment: The finger positions still get messed up if I copy the right hand's armature position over to the left.

Comment: yes because you also use some IKs for your fingers, so you also need to correct their own pole angles

Comment: yeah, I've done that as well. I've even reset the position, rotation and scale of every bone, but the fingers are still completely twisted out of proportion. I've added a screenshot to the first post.
EDIT: Turning off the influence for each finger IK fixes them, but is it wise to do that...?

Comment: well, I don't know, it's the choice you've made, I personally prefer to use other techniques for the hand  ;)